# log all SQL queries that Hangfire sends to database

Tags: .net-core, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I am currently using Hangfire 1.8.4 in my project, with SQL Server as job storage (using Hangfire.SqlServer 1.8.4). I am trying to find a way to log all SQL queries that Hangfire sends to my SQL Server database for execution.